# NodeJs, how to get full STDERR message displayed?

Tags: node.js, express, stderr, child-process

please help me how I can get full error string (to pass in res.send()) from process? For example in console now I getting printed:

```
Child Process STDERR: src/sketch.ino: In function ‘void setup()’:
src/sketch.ino:17:11: error: ‘led’ was not declared in this scope
src/sketch.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
src/sketch.ino:23:15: error: ‘led’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [.build/atmega328/src/sketch.o] Error 1
```

But when i pass **res.send('Error:\n'+ stderr);**, I get printed only **"Error: src/sketch.ino: In function ‘voi"**. Why it cuts message? And how to pass full one?

This is my code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var inoVerify = exec('ino build -m atmega328', { cwd: codeFile.projectPath }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+ stderr);
    if (stderr)
        res.send('Error:\n'+ stderr);                   
});
```

Comment: Have you tried res.end() instead of res.send()? The text returned is exactly 32 characters which is curious. Maybe it's hitting some buffer limit?

Comment: Yech, I tried res.end() - same problem. Yes I think you are right it is some limitation which are releated to exec proces.

Answer (score 2):

This is some exec limitatio.
I changed this sample to use spawn proces instead like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var inoVerify    = spawn('ino', ['build', '-m', 'atmega328'], { cwd: codeFile.projectPath });

inoVerify.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

inoVerify.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  res.end('stderr: ' + data);
});

inoVerify.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

By example from  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options